# Python 3: My class function doesn't run like I want

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python programming and about to finish my first small python game. It's basically a python pet which when the user types some commands you get set of responses. I put the function into my pet class but it's not working. It's only executing the first 2 lines. Giving me the option to input but nothing else.

```
import random
play = True

class Pypet:
    def __init__(self,name,photo,phrases,age,hungry,thirsty):
        self.name = name
        self.photo = photo
        self.phrases = phrases
        self.age = age
        self.hungry = hungry
        self.thirsty = thirsty

    def stats(self):
        print('Hey its me ' + self.name)
        if self.hungry:
            if self.thirsty:
                print(self.name + ' is hungry and thirsty!')
            else:
                print(self.name + ' is ')
        else:
            print('My stomach is going to explode *BURBS*')

    def run(self):
        while play:
            print('#################')
            user = input().lower
            if user == 'help':
                for command in commands:
                    print(command)
            elif user == commands[0]:
                print(random.choice(self.phrases))
            elif user == commands[1]:
                print('Omnomnom')
                self.hungry = False
            elif user == commands[2]:
                self.stats()
            elif user == commands[3]:
                if pypet.thirsty:
                    print('Luk luk luk thanks!')
                    self.thirsty = False
                else:
                    print('Im not thirsty!')
            elif user not in commands:
                print('Unknown command!')



commands = ['chat', 'feed', 'stats', 'give water', 'quit']

py1 = Pypet('Lexit','-_-',['Shaq','bored af','Maaaaan'], 15, True, True)
py2 = Pypet('BabyLexit',':))',['Daadddyy','wabadabadabdu','chabadabaduu'], 15, True, True)


py1.run()
```

When I run this I can input but it always returns me Unknown command and continues the loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

you are missing calling parenthesis here:

```
user = input().lower()   # <---- missing parenthesis
```

The program now works:

```
import random

play = True

class Pypet:
    def __init__(self,name,photo,phrases,age,hungry,thirsty):
        self.name = name
        self.photo = photo
        self.phrases = phrases
        self.age = age
        self.hungry = hungry
        self.thirsty = thirsty

    def stats(self):
        print('Hey its me ' + self.name)
        if self.hungry:
            if self.thirsty:
                print(self.name + ' is hungry and thirsty!')
            else:
                print(self.name + ' is ')
        else:
            print('My stomach is going to explode *BURBS*')

    def run(self):
        while play:
            print('#################')
            user = input().lower()     # <---- added parenthesis
            if user == 'help':
                for command in commands:
                    print(command)
            elif user == commands[0]:
                print(random.choice(self.phrases))
            elif user == commands[1]:
                print('Omnomnom')
                self.hungry = False
            elif user == commands[2]:
                self.stats()
            elif user == commands[3]:
                if pypet.thirsty:
                    print('Luk luk luk thanks!')
                    self.thirsty = False
                else:
                    print('Im not thirsty!')
            elif user not in commands:
                print('Unknown command!')



commands = ['chat', 'feed', 'stats', 'give water', 'quit']

py1 = Pypet('Lexit','-_-',['Shaq','bored af','Maaaaan'], 15, True, True)
py2 = Pypet('BabyLexit',':))',['Daadddyy','wabadabadabdu','chabadabaduu'], 15, True, True)

py1.run()
```

#### output:

if the input on the prompt is: `help`:

```
#################
help
chat
feed
stats
give water
quit
#################
```

Comment: IMO, the question should have rather been flagged as off-topic and unlikely to be of help to future readers, don't you think? While you're answer could have been a comment.

Comment: your, not you're answer!